# htaccess redirect 301 before other rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My htaccess look like this:

```
# Prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes

redirect 301 /old.html http://blablabla.pl/new
redirect 301 /other-page.html http://blablabla.pl/new-page
redirect 301 /xxx.html http://blablabla.pl/zzz

# Prevent visitors from viewing files directly
<FilesMatch "\.(sdb|md|html|txt)$">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# URL rewrites
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(inc/|themes/|tmp/).*\.(php|html)$ - [F,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm using CMS that use html files as templates (there are variables, php code etc.). In htaccess of this CMS there are rules to prevent visitors from viewing html files directly. I moved one page to this CMS and wanted to do 301 redirect from old pages but it's not working - i'm getting 403 forbidden error. Is there a way to execute 301 redirect before other rules?

Comment: Comment `Options` line and all of `FilesMatch` and retest your 301 rules.

Comment: This will work but it's not solution.

Comment: First test and find out it works or not. This is only for testing purpose.

Comment: Yes - it works (even without commenting Options line).

Comment: ok can you clarify what is `FilesMatch` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
(...)
# Prevent visitors from viewing files directly
<FilesMatch "\.(sdb|md|html|txt)$">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "(old\.html)|(other-page\.html)|(xxx\.html)">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
(...)
```